# Is there a allowed pattern regex to validate List<AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name>

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, availability-zone

I wanted to have a regex to ensure user provides 2 elements to parameter which is List

`AvailabilityZones:
    Description: List of Availability Zones to use for the subnets in the VPC. Only
      two Availability Zones are used for this deployment, and the logical order of
      your selections is preserved.
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name>
    AllowedPattern: "(([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-([0-9a-z]+))"
    ConstraintDescription: Two Availability Zones must be added.`

The above pattern does not validate 2 entries. Can someone help share how to effectively handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `Type` as List, AWS itself will handle validation of inputs and also ensures that input is list. So, removing `AllowedPattern` should resolve your issue.

Edit-1

Please check the following regex.

`^[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9a-z]+(?:,[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9a-z]+)+$`

It should solve your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @krisnik. I want to error out if the user does not provide '2' elements to the list. And not able to find a pattern or other ways to error out if less than 2 elements are provided as inputs for this list.

Comment: I had a hack for similar issue in my cf templates. What is your criteria? You allow only 2 inputs or do you accept inputs >= 2 ?

Comment: my case needs >=2.

Comment: @Sasi please check if edit 1 works. I have verified it in Online regex validator.

Comment: Thank @krisnik for the regex. I am sorry it did not work in the cloudformation case. I have noticed below shown during cloudformation preview and it matches with the above regex, but I don't think list in cloudformation is using ',' as the separator (I tried other patterns colon, next line and ', ' but it did not work)
AvailabilityZones
    us-east-2a,us-east-2b

Comment: Hi @Sasi, missed the notification. How about trying it with Type: String?

Comment: I think making it a string would work, but it adds complexity to end user to enter the right AZ's.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html -- Documentation says you can use AllowedPattern only for String datatypes. Guess, this is the limitation which you have to work with.